# How to put selected list values inside array in vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue application where I have to select two elements from an list component and then put them inside an array.Right now I have my list and I can select them thanks to vuetify I binded it to an array with v-model I can console log it inside of an array but what I want to achieve is something like this:

```js
{
   "meetingName":"",
   "meetingUrl":"",
   "participants":{
     participant1: "Hasan",
     participant2: "Turan"
   }
}
```

instead I am getting right now this:

```js
{
   "meetingName":"",
   "meetingUrl":"",
   "participants":[
      "Hasan",
      "Turan"
   ]
}
```

Could someone look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it?

html:

```html
 <template>
  <v-container>
      <v-row>
      <v-col cols="4">
        <v-card>
        <v-list>
        <v-list-item-group
            v-model="model"
            multiple
            color="indigo"
            v-model="model.participants"
            
        >
          <v-list-item
              v-for="(item, i) in voterArrayFilteredByTime"
              :key="item.voterUniqueName"
              :value="item.voterUniqueName"
              v-on:click= "generateGroup"
          >
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.voterUniqueName"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

an here is the method with which I want to console log it but it does not work like I said I am just getting numbers.

```html
      <script>
        import axios from "axios";
        
        export default {
          name: "AddGroupsModal",
        
          data : ()=>({
          singleSelect: false,
          selection: "",
          model:{ meetingName: "", meetingUrl: "", participants: [] },

        methods: {

        
       generateGroup(){
   
      console.log(this.model)

  }
        }
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems in your markup is it has *two* bindings to `v-model` when there should be just one (the last one in this case):

```html
<v-list-item-group
  v-model="model"❌
  multiple
  color="indigo"
  v-model="model.participants"❌
>
```

The `v-list` components can't create the expected value format, but you can use a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) along with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object from the array entries:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    computedParticipants() {
      return this.model.participants.reduce((obj, name, i) => {
        obj[`participant${i + 1}`] = name
        return obj
      }, {})


      // OR:
      const obj = {}
      this.model.participants.forEach((name, i) => {
        obj[`participant${i + 1}`] = name
      })
      return obj
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/computing-object-from-string-array-l8b50?file=/src/components/AddGroupsModal.vue)